# How to show one label per multi-polygon in open layers 3?

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm having an issue trying to figure out how to show one label per multipolygon in OL3. It currently shows the label for every polygon which is not ideal under any circumstance in this particular scenario.

[image: screenshot]

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    url: 'resources/ol3/countries.geojson'
}),
style: function (feature, resolution) {
    style.getText().setText(resolution < 10000 ? feature.get('NAME') : '');
    style.getFill().setColor('rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)');
    return styles;
}});
```

I'd like to show the label on the largest polygon if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One more option for the client side is to label just the bigger one, out of the polygon parts of the multipolygon.
For this option you dont need any control on the server-side. So use the following code or go direclty to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/ksemywLj/) to see it in action:

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  style: function (feature, resolution) {
    var polyStyleConfig = {
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
        width: 1
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0,0.3)'
      })
    }
    var textStyleConfig = {
      text:new ol.style.Text({
        text:resolution < 100000 ? feature.get('NAME') : '' ,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: "#000000" }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: "#FFFFFF", width: 2 })
      }),
      geometry: function(feature){
        var retPoint;
        if (feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'MultiPolygon') {
          retPoint =  getMaxPoly(feature.getGeometry().getPolygons()).getInteriorPoint();
        } else if (feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'Polygon') {
          retPoint = feature.getGeometry().getInteriorPoint();
        }
        console.log(retPoint)
        return retPoint;
      }
    }
    var textStyle = new ol.style.Style(textStyleConfig);
    var style = new ol.style.Style(polyStyleConfig);
    return [style,textStyle];
  },
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    wrapX: false
  })
});
```

You also need a helper function to verify which one is the bigger polygon:

```
function getMaxPoly(polys) {
  var polyObj = [];
  //now need to find which one is the greater and so label only this
  for (var b = 0; b < polys.length; b++) {
    polyObj.push({ poly: polys[b], area: polys[b].getArea() });
  }
  polyObj.sort(function (a, b) { return a.area - b.area });

  return polyObj[polyObj.length - 1].poly;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is what i'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is not supported by ol3, at least not 'natively'.  There are several ways to accomplish what you want but I don't think doing it on the 'client side' is the best approach.

## 1 - Simple and fast way, server-side

If you have control over your data / server, then I'd manage which label to show from there.  You could create a 'label-specific' field that contains a copy of the text you want to show, and for those you don't leave it blank.  That would work if you only want the biggest chunk of island to always have the label.

## 2 - complex and slow way - client-side

On the client side, in your style function, you could loop in each feature and collect those having the same name as the feature attempting to be labelled, then compare their geometry area.  Only label the feature if it has no other features of the same name having a bigger area.

This solution could also be implemented on the server-side.  You could return an extra field with value 1 if the feature is the one with the largest area among those sharing the same name, and 0 if it doesn't.  You would only label features with this field = 1.